# pass parameter to controller with forms in laravel-9

Tags: laravel, forms, routes, controller, laravel-9

i want to send `$category` to controller but when i recive `$category` in controller i found that it is empty

my form in edit.blade.php

```
    <form action="{{ route('categoryUpdate', $category) }}" method="post" class="ui form">
        @method('put')
        @csrf
        <div class="field">
            <label for="title">title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{$category->title}}" />  
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="description">description</label>
            <textarea name="description">{{$category->description}}</textarea>
           
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="active">status</label>
            <select name="active">
                <option value="0" @if($category->active==0) selected @endif>Not Active</option>
                <option value="1" @if($category->active==1) selected @endif> Active</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <button type="submit" class="ui primary button"> edit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

my web.php

```
Route::get('/category/{category}',[CategoryController::class,'show'])->name('categoryShow');
Route::get('/category/edit/{category}',[CategoryController::class,'edit'])->name('categoryEdit');
```

my controller

```
public function update(UpdateCategoryRequest $request, Category $category)
    {
        dd($category);
    }
```

Comment: You haven't post the routes for the update function but in order for the $category to work you have for pass the id. Are you sure the $category in your form has the id property? In your browse networking the post request has it ? Can you show us an example of the request and the payload of it ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the updates you need to do this:
Changes in the form:

```
<form action="{{ route('categoryUpdate', $category) }}" method="post" class="ui form">
        @csrf
        <div class="field">
            <label for="title">title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{$category->title}}" />  
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="description">description</label>
            <textarea name="description">{{$category->description}}</textarea>
           
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="active">status</label>
            <select name="active">
                <option value="0" @if($category->active==0) selected @endif>Not Active</option>
                <option value="1" @if($category->active==1) selected @endif> Active</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <button type="submit" class="ui primary button"> edit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/category/{category}',[CategoryController::class,'store'])->name('categoryStore');
Route::post('/category/edit/{category}',[CategoryController::class,'update'])->name('categoryUpdate');
```

When we deal with API we use `PUT` to update the entity, but when you deal with web form you use a `POST` method and that is most popular way to update the entity.

Comment: you can use put or patch for the route, we have method spoofing for forms

Comment: This methods works the same way